# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_root'

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter, caesar-cipher

i am trying to create caesar cipher program using tkinter, when i try to convert an Entry from the user from a string into an Int i get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_root'.
I already tried using 'stextentry = int(stextentry)' and i know it works, but i need to use the other version of that line of code for this script to work on another program. I don't know how to get rid of the error so i'm hoping someone could help me, by the way, this is not homework and it doesn't have anything to do with school.

```
from tkinter import *
def Encryption():

    ptextentry = ptext.get()
    stextentry = stext.get()
    stextentry = IntVar(stextentry)# <------------------- Error is here
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    cipher = " "
    for c in ptextentry:
        if c in alpha:
            cipher += alpha[(alpha.index(c)+stextentry) % (len(alpha))]
    print (cipher)
global P_Text_E, P_Text_L, S_K_L, S_K_E, plain_text, cctk
cctk = Tk()
ptext = StringVar()
stext = StringVar()
P_Text_L = Label(cctk, text="Enter plain text:").grid(row=0, column=0)
P_Text_E = Entry(cctk, textvariable=ptext).grid(row=0, column=1)
S_K_L = Label(cctk, text="Enter shift key:").grid(row=1, column=0)
S_K_E = Entry(cctk, textvariable=stext).grid(row=1, column=1)
Encrypt_B = Button(cctk, text="Encrypt plain text", command = Encryption).grid(row=2, columnspan =3)
Exit_cctk_B = Button(cctk, text="Exit").grid(row=3, columnspan =3)
cctk.title("Caesar Cipher Program")
cctk.mainloop()**
```

Comment: `global` doesn't create global variables. All variables created outside functions/classes automatically are global. You use `global` inside function to inform function that you want to use external variable instead of creating local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
stextentry = IntVar(value=stextentry)
```

single argument without `value=` is treated as `parent` so you can do

```
stextentry = IntVar(cctk)
stextentry.set(stextentry)
```

or

```
stextentry = IntVar(cctk, stextentry)
```

but you could do in one line

```
stextentry = IntVar(value=stext.get())
```

But now `stextentry` is `IntVar` so you have to use `stextentry.get()` in

```
cipher += alpha[(alpha.index(c) + stextentry.get() ) % (len(alpha))]
```

---

**BTW:** if you do

```
 var = Widget(...).grid(...)
 var = Widget(...).pack(...)
```

then you assign `None` to `var` because `grid()`/`pack()` always returns `None`

You have to do in two lines

```
 var = Widget(...)
 var.grid(...)
```

or without variable

```
 Widget(...).grid(...)
```

---

**EDIT:** full code - more readable: better variable names, empty lines.

```
import tkinter as tk
import string

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

ALPHA = string.ascii_lowercase
LENGTH = len(ALPHA)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def encryption():

    cipher = ""

    for char in plain_text.get():
        if char in ALPHA:
            cipher += ALPHA[(ALPHA.index(char) + shift_int.get()) % LENGTH]

    result_text.set(cipher)

    print(cipher)

# --- main ---

cctk = tk.Tk()
cctk.title("Caesar Cipher Program")

plain_text = tk.StringVar()
shift_int = tk.IntVar()
result_text = tk.StringVar()

l = tk.Label(cctk, text="Enter plain text:", anchor="e")
l.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")

e = tk.Entry(cctk, textvariable=plain_text)
e.grid(row=0, column=1)

l = tk.Label(cctk, text="Enter shift key:", anchor="e")
l.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e")

e = tk.Entry(cctk, textvariable=shift_int)
e.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = tk.Button(cctk, text="Encrypt plain text", command=encryption)
b.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

l = tk.Label(cctk, text="Result:", anchor="e")
l.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e")

l = tk.Label(cctk, textvariable=result_text, anchor="w") # place for result
l.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

b = tk.Button(cctk, text="Exit", command=cctk.destroy)
b.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

cctk.mainloop()
```